# Product of two measure preserving transformation

Tags: measure-theory

Is the product of two measure preserving transformation also measure preserving?

Comment: The product may be not well defined. Do you rather mean the composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the interval $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, and let $f(x)=x$. This is clearly measure-preserving, but $f(x)\cdot f(x)=x^2$ is not.